# Adding JS file in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I added `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>` in Blade file. But I am not getting output when I am browsing. I used `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan optimize:clear` command. But the output is as like before.

I added `<div id="app"><prayer_time></prayer_time></div>`. This is working fine.

How can I solve the issue ?

Comment: Is your script part outside of the `@section` part in the blade file?

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably putting the script part outside of the `@section` block in your template, which in turn does not render anything.

If you only need the script on that particular page, I would suggest using the `@push` method, like this in your template file:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
@endpush
```

Here you can [read more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#stacks) about the `@push` functionality.

Comment: Thanks @brance I tried both. I placed `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>` inside `@section` and I used your way. But none of them is working. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the blade php code. Did you also clear the view cache?

Comment: In order to use @push('scripts') you need to have @stack('scripts') in your layout blade